# Resize home partition taking space from root partition?

Tags: arch-linux, partition, disk

I'm on Arch Linux and this is the overview of the current disk layout:

```
❯ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
nvme0n1     259:0    0 476,9G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0     1G  0 part /boot
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   300G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 175,9G  0 part /home
```

```
❯ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p2  295G   82G  198G  30% /
/dev/nvme0n1p3  173G   87G   77G  53% /home
/dev/nvme0n1p1 1022M   84M  939M   9% /boot
```

Since I found out that I may have allocated too much space to the `root` partition and too little to the `home` partition, I would like to know if it is possible to transfer some available space from one to the other. I have thought of the following steps:

1. Backup the whole system
2. Boot from live arch usb
3. Resize the root partition (this will give me some unallocated space)
4. Delete the current /home partition
5. Create and format a new home partition on `nvme0n1/nvme0n1p3`
6. Transfer the old /home files to the newly created part

Supposing these steps so far are sound, there are some more steps to be followed of course. What do I have to do exactly to restore the old system without making much of a mess? I'd like to avoid reinstalling from 0 and preserve installed programs, docker images, etc.

Also, while I'm at it, I'd like to ask:

- Which are some good root - home size considering I use docker a lot and potentially will install a decent number of programs in the future (right now I've used ~82G)?
- Do you have any suggestions for an exclude_files list for `rsync` when cloning the /home partition (like caches, node_modules, site_packages, etc.)?

Comment: This is about Ubuntu's /home, not sure how similar Arch is: http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/40992/what-files-and-directories-can-be-excluded-from-a-backup-of-the-home-directory/40997#40997 & 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270519/rsync-exclude-a-directory-but-include-a-subdirectory/37219769#37219769

Comment: Just to clarify, this comment is referring to the second point of the post scriptum section.
"Do you have any suggestions for an exclude_files list for `rsync` when cloning the /home partition (like caches, node_modules, site_packages, etc.)?"

Comment: do you actually need / and /home to be separate partitions?  unless you've got a good reason for that, you're probably better off with just a / partition, with /home being a sub-directory on /.

Comment: @cas I do since it's way more flexible IMO: https://askubuntu.com/questions/142695/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-having-a-separate-home-partition

Comment: It's flexible in some ways, inflexible in others.  Your question indicates that you've run into one of the ways that it is inflexible - you have to guess in advance how much space you think each partition might need and hope you got it right.  Space allocation is one of the reasons I prefer ZFS datasets instead of partitions or LVs - all datasets have access to all available space in the entire pool (unless I set the `quota` or `reservation` properties for them - either of which can be changed at any time with one simple command - no need to move files around or re-partition any drives).

Answer (score -1):

First, you must boot from a Live USB.  You can only modify a disk when none of the disk's partitions is mounted.

Read `man gparted resize2fs` before you start.

IDK if `gparted` is on the Arch Live USB, but a Live Gparted USB is available.

Run `gparted`. **Be SURE to select the right disk!**.

Select `nvme0n1p2`, shrink it (to 100GB? YMMV), by reducing its upper limit. This will create unallocated space between `nvme0n1p2` and `nvme0n1p3`.

Select `nvme0n1p3`. Adjust the lower limit to consume the unallocated space.

Click on `Apply` at the bottom of the page to have `gparted` actually make the changes.

Wait until `gparted` completes. It has a lot to do.

Remove the Live USB, and reboot

Read `man gparted resize2fs` before you start.

Yes, the above paragraph is repeated. IMHO, the reading of `msn` pages is a sacred duty.

Comment: I knew about this procedure and if I understood correctly what gparted is doing under the hood is moving the unallocated part on the right of the home partition before being able to extend the old partition. But I've also read around that this process (depending on the sizes of course) may take a really long time and it's prone to system breaks. That's way I was actually going after a complete /home remove and reallocation, leveraging the fact the the root part is independent.